# paypal PPAPIService new SDK

Tags: api, sdk, paypal

Concerning the new Paypal SDK, there is almost no useful example code, and the Internet is littered with examples of the old SDK.  My question concerns making an API request for a third party paypal account for which i have obtained the token and secretToken through the permissions API.

In attempting to construct a PPAPIService object, where is the list of possible sevice names?
ie: $this->serviceName = $serviceName; (in the constructor) What is the string syntax for these?

In regards to the makeRequest method, how do I define the $apiMethod variable, and what is the format of the $params variable?  What are the different parameters?

A simple example of how to just obtain the account balance of the authorized third party account would be extremely helpful.
I am using PHP.

from the PPAPIService.php file:

```
class PPAPIService
{
public $endpoint;
public $serviceName;
private $logger;

public function __construct($serviceName = "")
{
    $this->serviceName = $serviceName; //is there ANY documentation about the syntax and types of service names?
    $config = PPConfigManager::getInstance();
    $this->endpoint = $config->get('service.EndPoint');
    $this->logger = new PPLoggingManager(__CLASS__);
}

public function setServiceName($serviceName)
{
    $this->serviceName = $serviceName;
}


public function makeRequest($apiMethod, $params, $apiUsername = null, $accessToken = null, $tokenSecret = null)
{
//what are the apiMethod types? syntax? and params? type.. options...??
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you do not have to create a PPAPIService object directly. Let's say you want to use the Invoicing SDK, here's what you would do

```
$invoiceService = new InvoiceService();
$invoiceService->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$invoiceService->setTokenSecret($tokenSecret);
$createInvoiceResponse = $invoiceService->CreateInvoice($createInvoiceRequest);
```

There's one service class (such as InvoiceService in this code snippet) per API that you would instantiate as per your needs. The API username/password are picked from the configuration file and the access token/token secret are set via code since they typically tend to be different for different invocations.

Which API are you trying to call, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

To answer on your other concern, the new PayPal SDK's have all the required samples bundled within the SDK itself. The SDK + Samples canbe downloaded from

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index